How to get a custom program to run when uninstall from Windows is chosen?
I've had many problems with InstallShield and all of the baggage that goes along with all of the .msi installers. So I've been toying with the idea of writing my own installer framework. One of the first problems I anticipated running up against though was uninstallation. When the user opens Settings->Apps or appwiz.cpl and double clicks on the program the uninstallation starts. I thought this would be initiated by the string stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{GUID}\UninstallString, (which takes the form of "msiexec.exe /x{GUID}"),so I modified that value to point at a simple app I had written that basically pops open a hello-world dialog. But that's not working. I found this in 1 other place in the registry and changed it there as well. It still initiates the uninstall of the app as if it's running msiexec.exe /x{GUID} (which is the value I replaced). Anyone have any thoughts on how I can change this behavior?

UninstallString is indeed the command executed when you uninstall a program from the Windows UI. UninstallString and DisplayName are the only required values in an uninstaller subkey.
However, modifying another applications is not the best way to test this because you might edit the wrong value (WOW6432Node in your key means you are editing a 32-bit application in this case). Some versions of Windows might also cache this information somewhere else. It is better to just write your own entry for testing:
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SoTest]
"UninstallString"="cmd.exe /c echo.Uninstall me?&pause&reg delete HKCU\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\SoTest /f"
"DisplayName"="Uninstaller Test"

(Save as test.reg and double-click it)
